# How to fix error: "missing argument for parameter"

Tags: swift

I'm following Udacity course right now. Codes above `func screenVIP (age: Int, onGuestList: Bool, knowsTheOwner: Bool)` are all written by them. I wrote the ones below but "Missing argument for parameter 'knowsTheOwner' in call" keeps coming up.

```
// Here are some variables to represent a person who wants to come in to the club
var name: String = "Ayush"
var age: Int = 19
var onGuestList: Bool = false
var knowsTheOwner: Bool = true

// Helper functions for admitting or denying entrance
func admit(person: String) {
    print("\(person), come and party with us!")
}

func deny(person: String) {
    print("Sorry, \(person), maybe you can go play Bingo with the Android team.")
}

func sendToOwner(knowsTheOwner: Bool, person: String) {
    if knowsTheOwner {
        print("\(person), buddy, come on in!")
    } else {
        print("Who is this joker?")
    }
}

// Functions to determine which clubgoers should be admitted
func screenVIP(age: Int, onGuestList: Bool, knowsTheOwner: Bool) {
    if  onGuestList && age >= 21 {
        admit(person: name)
    } else if knowsTheOwner{
        sendToOwner(person: name) // <-- Error here
    } else {
        deny(person: name)
    }
}
screenVIP(age: age, onGuestList: onGuestList, knowsTheOwner: knowsTheOwner)
```

Comment: Look at the `sendToOwner` function? How many parameters does it have? Now look at how you call it. How many arguments are you passing?

Comment: Read the error. Look at your code. The error message is telling you _exactly_ what is wrong. Look at `func sendToOwner(knowsTheOwner: Bool, person: String)`. Look at `sendToOwner(person: name)`. Look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

1) Give a default value to the parameter `knowsTheOwner`.

```
    func sendToOwner(knowsTheOwner: Bool = true, person: String) {
    if knowsTheOwner {
        print("\(person), buddy, come on in!")
    } else {
        print("Who is this joker?")
    }
}
```

2) If you do not want to give a default value to the parameter `knowsTheOwner` then, do this:

```
 func screenVIP(age: Int, onGuestList: Bool, knowsTheOwner: Bool) {
    if  onGuestList && age >= 21 {
        admit(person: name)
    } else if knowsTheOwner{
        sendToOwner(knowsTheOwner: knowsTheOwner,person: name) // <-- knowsTheOwner here is the argument from above 
    } else {
        deny(person: name)
    }
}
```

You have to do this because there is no default value for the argument as the error says. There must be some value to it.